# Image size in css for php images loading from a file

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying add css code to handle my image sizes that are auto loading from a file source. I'm using a php scrpt to load the images and it's working, but i can't change the size of the images using css for a responsive site. I'm using masonry to display images and again this is working.

I'm showing the php which is working. I need help to manipulate the size of the images in the .project

```
                   <div class='project'>


        <?php 
        // Image extensions
        $image_extensions = array("png","jpg","jpeg","gif");

        // Target directory
        $dir = 'img/';
        if (is_dir($dir)){

            if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
                $count = 1;

                // Read files
                while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){

                    if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){


                        // Image path
                        $image_path = "img/".$file;


                        $image_ext = pathinfo($image_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                        // Check its not folder and it is image file
                        if(!is_dir($image_path) && 

                            in_array($image_ext,$image_extensions)){
                            ?>

                            <!-- Image -->

                                <img src="<?php echo $image_path; ?>" alt="" title=""/>
                            </a>
                            <!-- --- -->
                            <?php

                        }
                    }

                }
                closedir($dh);
            }
        }
        ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Css can't mainpulate images, only can add style (For example, half size than his parent, 20% brightness, blue border,etc..) but you can't manipulate it.

For make this search in Google an script for resizing or cutting images in PHP. But in masonry this doesn't have sense, the magic of masonry is to adapt any size to any layout (via Javascript).

Comment: I would disagree about CSS - styling is a form of manipulation, so in a sense CSS can manipulate images, although to a very limited forms of maniputations. Some browser have the support of invertig image colors via CSS. But not all

Comment: Yep, but this manipulation is a layer above the image, in other words, you can't manipulate the original image (like cut it)

Comment: A sad truth that is =), It's hard to tell what exactly OP needs - by the looks of it css should be enough. The OP's code shows no CSS at all. =)